# Options don't display when click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making an option button *(the tree dots above right)*. When click on it, the options must be show. Click again and the options hide. Below is my code, but it doesn't work. Can you look at it?

```js
$("body").ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".options-knop", function() {

        if (this.nextSibling.style.display == "none"){
            this.nextSibling.style.display = 'block !important';
        } else {
            this.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.img-container {
    height: 100px;
}

.artist {
    transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.artist-outer {
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.artist .naam {
    width: 190px;
}

.options-knop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 325px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: black !important;
    transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

.artist-outer:nth-child(6n+4),
.artist-outer:nth-child(6n+5),
.artist-outer:nth-child(6n+6) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.artist:nth-child(6n+4) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+5) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+6) .options-knop {
    background-color: white;
}
.artist:nth-child(6n+1) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+2) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+3) .options-knop {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.options-knop:hover{
    background-color: #a3a3a3 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.artist-outer:hover{
    background-color: #545454 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.options-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    left: 260px;
}

.options-list ul {
    padding: 0;
}

.naam {
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clearfix col-md-4 artist-outer' id='656556255'>
    <div class='artist'>
        <div class='artist-info'>
            <div class='img-wrapper'>
                <img style="width:100px" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYnSM.gif'/>
            </div>
            <p class='naam'><b>Random naam</b></p>
            <p>Volgers op Spotify: XXX</p>
        </div>
        <div class='options-knop'>...</div>
        <div class='options-list list-group' style='display: none;'>
            <a class='list-group-item'>Toon albums</a>
            <a class='list-group-item'>Profiel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready();   and $("body").on()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using JQuery you can use function **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** :

```
if ( $(this).next().css('display') == "none")
     $(this).next().show();
else
     $(this).next().hide();
```

Or simply use **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** to toggle the display of your div `show/hide` without using condition :

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`jQuery.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".options-knop", function() {
        $(this.nextSibling).toggle( );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.options-knop').click(function (e)
     {
        $('.options-list').toggle();
   });
});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.img-container {
    height: 100px;
}

.artist {
    transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.artist-outer {
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.artist .naam {
    width: 190px;
}

.options-knop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 325px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: black !important;
    transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

.artist-outer:nth-child(6n+4),
.artist-outer:nth-child(6n+5),
.artist-outer:nth-child(6n+6) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.artist:nth-child(6n+4) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+5) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+6) .options-knop {
    background-color: white;
}
.artist:nth-child(6n+1) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+2) .options-knop,
.artist:nth-child(6n+3) .options-knop {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.options-knop:hover{
    background-color: #a3a3a3 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.artist-outer:hover{
    background-color: #545454 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.options-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    left: 260px;
}

.options-list ul {
    padding: 0;
}

.naam {
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
  color:black;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clearfix col-md-4 artist-outer' id='656556255'>
    <div class='artist'>
        <div class='artist-info'>
            <div class='img-wrapper'>
                <img style="width:100px" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYnSM.gif'/>
            </div>
            <p class='naam'><b>Random naam</b></p>
            <p>Volgers op Spotify: XXX</p>
        </div>
        <div class='options-knop'>...</div>
        <div class='options-list list-group' style='display: none;'>
            <a class='list-group-item'>Toon albums</a>
            <a class='list-group-item'>Profiel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The options are now visible just add the color to class list-group-item

Answer (score 1):

First of all for me I don't like to mix jquery with pure Javascript if its no need for that

in your code use

```
$(document).ready();
```

instead of

```
$("body").ready
```

and use

```
$("body").on();
```

instead of

```
$(document).on()
```

and to get next element with jquery you need to use **.next();** .. so jquery code should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".options-knop", function() {

        $(this).next('.options-list').slideToggle();

    });
});
```